# Etiquette on asking for donations of reputation to set a bounty

Tags: support, specific-question, bounties, unanswered-questions

My [question languishes on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070658/extra-user-profile-field-edited-only-by-admin-wordpress) with nary an answer nor comment. I would really like to know the answer to my quandry. I do believe that there exists a solution to my problem, but as yet, it has not come.

Would be okay to ask someone to donate their reputation toward a bounty on my question?

Is it even possible to *donate* reputation points to another user?

Comment: it would be great if you can leave me a comment why you think that this question is not unclear or not useful. Thank you.

Comment: on meta.SO, downvotes can also mean "i disagree with this opinion/proposal/whatever".  this is different from the other trilogy sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't donate reputation to other users -- that wouldn't really count as "reputation".  Rather than putting up a bounty, though, you should work to improve your question so that it can be more easily understood and answered.  Things like fixing up your grammar, describing what you've already tried, and providing detailed examples of the core problem you're trying to solve, all help.

Comment: Right now, the question pointed to looks like an attempt to breach Wordpress security, and it doesn't look like it should be on SO in any case.  I'd suggest explaining why anybody should help you do admin functions in Wordpress without being an admin, and what it has to do with programming.

Comment: @David Thornley: what is a security breach about adding a phone number to your wordpress profile if you want to be displayed to everybody? Using the link in my question I can implement it. My question is how I can code that only admin can add and edit that extra field. In my opinion is not related to security at all. Only if coded bad way and it is also why I am asking here. Maybe you can tell us more why it would be a security breach. I am happy to change my opinion.

Comment: @Radek:  It looked like it on first reading.  I edited the question to make what I misunderstood more clear.  I apologize for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @David Thornley: there is no need to appologize. It was perfectly right. Moreover I learnt that I have to formulate my questions better way...

Comment: so why the question was closed?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, SO reputation is not a financial instrument which you could donate to someone else or borrow from someone.

Comment: Heh, next we'll have people securitising SO accounts and causing the Global Reputation Crisis.

Comment: Or people loaning out more rep than they possess to people who could never pay it back. (That's my understanding of the current banking crisis)

Comment: All this depends of course on who you are basing. A Jon Skeet is probably an AAA, with a solid +200 per day. But the rest, much harder to estimate!

Answer (score 0):

You could, in theory, include in your question a request for upvotes, with the explanation of why you want the reputation.  This is generally considered in poor taste, and might well backfire.

The earlier suggestion of improving the question is probably much more likely to accomplish what you want.

Comment: note to potential downvoters: i knew ahead of time this would be an unpopular suggestion, so feel free.  *if you strike me down (low enuff), i will become more powerful than you can possibly imagine.*

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: long ago, it was proposed to allow for selling developers.sun.com's "[Duke Stars](http://developers.sun.com/forums/dukestars/)"<sup>†</sup> for charity, assuming some would pay to get their question answered even more promptly. I wonder if people would be more willing to donate to, for example, some Haiti relief fund when getting some reputation in return, instead of just donating without expecting anything.

<sup><sup>†</sup> then known as "Duke Dollars", which according to Yahoo! is something totally different nowadays...</sup>

Comment: When you practice some donating, don't make a production out of it. It might turn you into a small-time celebrity but it won't make you a saint. 
(paraphrased from Matthew 6:16 MSG)

Comment: @Ralph: why does your bible contain MSG?  i mean some basil or black pepper is nice for seasoning the Word, but monosodium glutamate?

Comment: @~quack MSG stands, as you might well know, for Message. The message bible is a modern transliteration by Eugene Peterson. It most of the time sparks new thoughts through unexpected translation.

Comment: @Ralph: nope, didn't know that.  huh.  "The Word -- The Message edition."  there's a microsoft joke in there somewhere.